# How to Detect if touch is inside the oval or not in android canvas?

Tags: canvas, android-canvas

I want to detect if touch in the canvas view is inside the oval or not.

Current code:

```
override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
    val rectF = RectF(200F, 300F, 100F, 100F)
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint)
}

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val value = super.onTouchEvent(event)
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->{
        return true
        } 
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
       // detect touch inside oval in canvas
      return true
      }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
      return true
      }
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare **the rectangle globally** in the class. Then you can just check if the rectangle contains the point of touch. Something like,

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val value = super.onTouchEvent(event)
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ->{
           return true
        } 
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
           if(rect.contains(event.x, event.y)) {
             // touched inside the oval
            } else {
             // touched in canvas, outside the oval
            }
           return true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            return true
        }
    }
    return value
}
```